# overriding colors for buttons on a wordpress theme with bootstrap buttons

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, button, colors

I'm trying change the colors on these buttons on a wordpress site

http://www.saylor.org/pathways/ and http://www.saylor.org/pathways/earn-college-credit/

the codes for the buttons on one page is

```
<a class=btn-green" href="/pathways/foundational-courses/'>Browse Courses</a>
```

Thanks in advance for any help anyone could provide

Comment: You can override the background color property as shown below in page where you want to override it or put it in css file to load in the end.

.course-wrap .btn-green {
    background-color: #FF0000;
}

Comment: Thanks.....I tried to put it on the CSS and on the bottom or the page but I still can't get it to work. any other ideas?  this is driving me crazy.

Comment: Can you please share how you have tried to add the css ?

Comment: I put on the bottom of the css sheet, if I send the link could you take a look?

Answer (score 0):

you should write in your css file

```
.btn-green a:hover{
    background-color: #099AD1;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks.....I tried to put it on the CSS and on the bottom or the page but I still can't get it to work. any other ideas?

Comment: Can you explain what the code does instead of just providing the solution?

Comment: background-color changes background color;color changes text color; text-decoration removes underline under text

Answer (score 0):

You need to put it as shown below with missing content. Check the missing content which you have not included

```
<style type="text/css">

 .course-wrap .btn-green {

 background-color: #FF0000;

 }
</style>
```

You can change the value of background color from **#FF0000** to any other value as per your requirement.

Comment: it's still not working :-( , I thought anything put on the custom CSS would override anything else.

Comment: On your page I can see your style tag is broken, it should be type="text/css". Correct and check again.

Comment: I'm working a development site http://wordpress-dev-01.sylr.org/ the code    <style type="text/css"> is how I have it entered...I also tried the bottom of the pages.

Comment: That's interesting, some how when I open the link and check its View Source it shows me broken style tag. You can load the page and check it view source to confirm or check line 559 here http://pastebin.com/KDV5VKjK

Comment: I'm so lost :-(....  I have tried everything I can think of. Can we do a screen share?

Comment: Can you please share some part of your code where you are putting above css  ?

Comment: I'm going to try to attach the link the custom CSS page; http://www.saylor.org/site/wp-admin/admin.php?page=st-framework-css-editor and then I tried to put it here; http://www.saylor.org/site/wp-admin/post.php?post=54294&action=edit